# (Java) Append elements to a String variable from String array up to specific index?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = new String[1024];
    int count = 0;
    test[count] = "33";
    count++;
    test[count] = "34";

    String s = new String();
```

This is just a simplified version, but I would like to append elements to a String variable s up to the index value of count without using StringBuilder, is there a way to do it? Thank you.

edit: without using loop as well, is there a String manipulation function I can use?

Comment: You want to append to `s` all `test[0..count]` values?

Comment: You could do in loop something like => for(int i=0; i<=count; i++) { s += test[i]; }

Comment: @ernest_k yes! means, my String s will be "3334"!

Comment: @Prakash13 sorry i forgot to mention without using loop as well!

Comment: @Ken You could make a method like everytime you increment count and insert in test[count]=something, also do s+=test[count] or s+=something

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is using [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) and [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-):

```
String s = String.join("", Arrays.copyOf(test, count + 1));
```

Which, with your test data, produces `3334`

Answer (score 0):

Dont quite understand what you want...
But I guess you could user char array？

```
char[] c = new char[maxCount] 
for(int i = 0;i<maxCount;i++){
  c[i] = "34";
}
```

String s = String.valueOf(c)

Hope this could help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, what you're asking for...

Concatenating consecutive numbers could be easily done with a stream:

```
String s = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1024)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the join function of String.
Assuming the test is the string array.

`String joinedString = String.join("", Arrays.stream(test).limit(count).collect(Collectors.toList()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.join()

> public class Main {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     String[] test = new String[1024];
>     int count = 0;
>     test[count] = "33";
>     count++;
>     test[count] = "34";
>
>     String s = new String();
>     System.out.println(s=String.join("", Arrays.copyOf(test, count + 1)));
> }
> ```
>
> }